# Query about np.loadtext() function

Tags: python, numpy

I've been trying to parse through a CSV File using the `NumPy` Module as shown below, where I've had to hard-code `dtype`, which can be seen below too.

```
def FileR(self,FileName):
    data = [('SecurityInfo', 'S64'),
                 ('Date', 'S64'),
                 ('Cost', 'float'),
                 ('Yield', 'float'),]      
    return data

def Gettheinfo(self):
    the_info = np.loadtxt('the.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows = 1, dtype = self.FileR('the.csv'))
    return the_info
```

Is there a way to use `np.loadtxt` without hard-coding `data`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your file is formatted, but I'm assuming it looks something like this:

```
SecurityInfo,Date,Cost,Yield
a string,another string,11.50,2110.3
more,stuff,43.15,343
```

Then you can use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), which is more powerful:

```py
np.genfromtxt('abc.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)
```

`dtype=None` will automatically determine the dtype of each column.

`names=True` will read the field names from the first line of the file.

Example:

```py
>>> np.genfromtxt('abc.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)
array([('a string', 'another string', 11.5, 2110.3),
       ('more', 'stuff', 43.15, 343.0)], 
      dtype=[('SecurityInfo', 'S8'), ('Date', 'S14'), ('Cost', '<f8'), ('Yield', '<f8')])
```